# Script to automate kadmin principal

Tags: bash, kerberos, principal

I am trying to write a script to automate kerberos principal and but the script is not working. Not sure what i am missing. Below is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Please enter space-delimited list of principal to create: " NEW_Principal

clear

echo "password" | kinit adminuser/admin ; echo "password" | kadmin

for i in $NEW_ORGS
do
        addprinc ${i}
        ${i}
        echo ""
done
```

---

Also tried writing this way:

```
################### create principal #############
pass="principal_password"
echo "password" | kinit adminuser/admin
printf "%b" "password" | kadmin
printf "%b" "addprinc principal_name\n$pass\n$pass"
```

But its not working in script.

Comment: What exactly is not working? Do you get any errors?

Comment: Thanks for response @bahrep... I have resolved this issue and posted the answer.

Answer (score 4):

I have done it. All I have to do is pass the command as a string. Here is the answer:

```
echo -e "${i}\n${i}" | kadmin -w "$krb_pass" -q "addprinc
```